# FFMPEG fails on pipe to pipe video decoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to decode a video from raw bytes using `ffmpeg -i pipe: -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -an -sn pipe:`, while the command exits with code 0, the stdout is empty and stderr contains the following message:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fa862816a00] stream 0, offset 0x2c: partial file
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv), 1080x1920, 50546 kb/s, 29 fps, 29 tbr, 14848 tbn, 14848 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fa862816a00] stream 0, offset 0x2c: partial file
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1080x1920, q=2-31, 1443225 kb/s, 29 fps, 29 tbn, 29 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 rawvideo
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

Any hint would be appreciated, as I don't have much experience with FFMPEG.

I can probe the same video without problem with `ffprobe -show_format -show_streams -of json pipe:`

Comment: As it says, "stream 0, offset 0x2c: partial file".  Generally, you can't pipe in a MP4/MOV. MPEGTS is the typical container for piping.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Does that mean, that if I have an MP4 file, I would first have to convert it to a different format that can be piped? Or is there any other alternative?

Comment: No, you will have to remux it to a workable container like MPEG TS.

Comment: Actually, I found a solution that works when you can control the files (see answer).

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the above question is potentially impossible, because:

> You generally cannot pipe mov (or mp4) files unless you used
> -movflags +faststart when encoding or if run tools/qt-faststart
> on the input file before piping it. - [Carl Eugen](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-June/032476.html)

This is, because they store crucial information needed to decode towards the end of the file by default, requiring a full load before being fully processable. However, they are able to store it towards the beginning, too. In that case, piping works.

Since I control the files I am working with, I could simply rewrite the files so that this information is stored towards their beginning and now the command from the question works. I used ffmpeg to do that: `ffmpeg -i <ORIGINAL_FILENAME> -c copy -map 0 -movflags +faststart <NEW_FILENAME>`.

I've written a small python script to do that for me:

```python
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import DEVNULL, PIPE, Popen

def convert_video_to_faststart(path: Path):
    tmp_path = str(path).replace(path.name, f"tmp_{path.name}")
    args = ["ffmpeg", "-i", str(path), "-c", "copy", "-map", "0", "-movflags", "+faststart",
            tmp_path]

    process = Popen(args, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    _, _ = process.communicate()
    if process.returncode != 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"ffmpeg error\n\n{err.decode('utf-8')}")
    path.unlink()
    Path(tmp_path).rename(path)
```